# Use of a mixin with the exit code

Tags: dart, mixins

Mixin Problem

Without the use of a mixin, the following code in the default_project works:

```
abstract class ProjectGen extends ConceptEntity<Project> {
```

With the use of the ConceptEntity mixin, there is a problem, without an error message, with the exit code=139 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, and the exit code=-1073741819 on Windows 7.

```
abstract class ProjectGen extends Object with ConceptEntity<Project> {
```

The restrictions on the ConceptEntity mixin in dartling are fulfilled:
ConceptEntity does not declare a constructor.
Its superclass is Object.
It does not ontain calls to super.

default_project
https://github.com/dzenanr/default_project
ProjectGen in lib/gen/default/project/projects.dart

dartling
https://github.com/dzenanr/dartling
ConceptEntity in lib/domain/model/entity.dart

```
class ConceptEntity<E extends ConceptEntity<E>> implements EntityApi {
```

Comment: When run from console it prints `Segmentation fault`. This is clearly a bug. Please report it at http://dartbug.com

Comment: Reported: Issue 23385 https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=23385&thanks=23385&ts=1430829914